# OpenERP : Multiple module overriding onchange function

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, openerp-7, overriding

I need to override `onchange_partner_id` function present in sale.order but I'm working on a system that already have a module overriding this function.
I tried to write my own `onchange_partner_id` with similar code :

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):
    res = super(sale_order, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part)
    // doing some stuff and adding it to res['value']['myfield']
return res
```

But my function isn't read by OpenERP.
So my question is, is it possible to have multiple function overriding the same function and if i's possible how do I proceed ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can override this method, for that you need to define new class in which inherit `sale.order` and define your method.

Your method will be called definitely.

```
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part, context=None):
        res = super(sale_order, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part,context=context)
        // doing some stuff and adding it to res['value']['myfield']
        return res
```

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem but I can't resolve it,
There is another module on the system that replace the original field and the original onchange function with :
`<field name="partner_id" position="replace">
    <field name="partner_id" on_change="onchange_partner_opt1_id(partner_id)" /> </field>`

Comment: And in a module which inherit sale.order, the module define onchange_partner_opt1_id(partner_id) :
`def onchange_partner_opt1_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):
//new instructions
`
Then another module inherit sale.order and override this function:
`def onchange_partner_opt1_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):
res = super(sale_order, self).onchange_partner_opt1_id(cr, uid, ids, part)
//blahblah
return res`

Comment: So I tried tu build a module with same specification than the inheriting one and he's never called by OpenERP ..

`class sale_order(osv.osv):

       _inherit = 'sale.order'

def onchange_partner_opt1_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):

          res = super(sale_order,self).onchange_partner_opt1_id(cr, uid, ids, part)
         res['value']['tag'] = 'test'
         return res
`
Any idea ? Thanks