# Overriding an overridden method in openerp 7?

Tags: python, openerp-7

I am trying to override the `name_get` method of the model product.product which was overridden by a different module. My questions are:

**Question 1**: Why is my `name_get` method not triggered unless I put the original overriding module in my descriptor file. Ex. `'depends': 'product_custom'`

**Question 2**: (overriding module is included in my descriptor file). My `name_get` gets called and context gets followed but after realeasing the mouse on the `one2many_list` field my context no longer get called setting the original overriding module `name_get` to be called.

My code:

```
if context.get('marker', False):
    # THIS IS CALLED WHEN ONE2MANY FIELD IS CLICKED
    for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        name = product.name
        res.append((product.id, name))
    return res
else:
    # THIS IS CALLED WHEN ONE2MANY FIELD IS RELEASED
    return super(overriding_module, self).name_get(cr, uid, ids, context)
```

I have added a marker on my XML and injected one using the `fields_view_get` method.

I have checked [this link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/using-name-get-how-to-shows-two-different-display-values-2589#answer-57376) as reference

My question is similar to this question in stackoverflow:

[OpenERP : Multiple module overriding onchange function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080690/openerp-multiple-module-overriding-onchange-function)

Comment: `name_get` must return a list of tuples: `res.append((product.id, name))`

Comment: Still same result with tuples instead of list.